# how to pass date parameter in a rest request query in python: sysparm_query

Tags: python, rest, web

what is the best way to filter a rest request by date?

would work passing a variable maybe like this:

```
today = date.today() today_90 = today - timedelta(days = 90)

service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1000&sysparm_query=sys_created_on**dates values here?**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to understanding your problem:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import requests

today = date.today() 
today_90 = today - timedelta(days = 90)


r = requests.get('https://xxxx.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1000&sysparm_query=sys_created_on>' + str(today_90) + '&sysparm_query=sys_created_on<' + str(today))
```

Comment: thank you friend, it worked the way i wanted